# Run node module from django app within a dockerized environment

Tags: node.js, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

1. I have a django-rest-framework app that runs within a dockerized environment and is exposed on localhost:8080.
2. I have a node module, folder with a node module(main.js). This node app is not served/exposed and cannot be accessed via an endpoint.
3. The only way in which I can run my node module is via a command line,

> node main.js '{args object}'

My Question:

I have to run the node module from python and I am not sure how to implement it. Here are my thoughts and for each thought, I wish to be guided(with code) on how to run it.

1. Create a post endpoint on my Django-app and from this endpoint pass the args/object that will be passed down to the node module.
2. Do I dockerize the Django and node modules in two separate containers. If I take this route how do I run the node module with the required arguments?
3. Do I just dockerize the Django-app(already done) and add the node folder in it and access it within the Django container. If I take this route how do I run the node module with the required arguments?

> I have not implemented any of the approaches above. I welcome any viable solutions.

Comment: Can you wrap the Node application in an Express wrapper?  That'd let you make a normal cross-container call to invoke it.

Comment: @DavidMaze

Yes, that I can do, so assume I expose the node js on localhost:3000, how'd I make the cross-container call?

Comment: With an ordinary HTTP library like `requests`, and using the mechanisms described in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/); use the other container's Compose service name as a host name.